# Selenium webdriver: Not able to locate the radio button element in FaceBook "Forgotten account?" link

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Details:

1. Click on "Forgotten account?" in `FaceBook` login page.
2. Give emailID (you can give any invalid/valid email here)
3. Click on "Search"

Then there will be two radio buttons as "Use my Google account" and "Email me a link to reset my". One will be selected default.

I am trying to check which one is selected and which one is not through the webdriver program. But I am getting element not found spite of trying with different locators.

I wrote the code in java.

Can any one help please?
I have tried the below things.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("send_email")
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id=send_email)]"));
```

error in elipse is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: .......

Comment: Please explain how any non-shady purpose would require automating this.

Comment: I am trying to do various validations on FB pages to explore more..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the selected input with

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[checked='1']"))
```

and then do

```
.getAttribute(‌​"value");
```

which will return you either "recover_openid" (use my google account) or "send_email".
But afaik it will work only for selected by default value. If you need to check which value is selected after you selected it - you should use react props and check that this input component has "checked=true".